# ember.js access sibling hierachy functions

Tags: javascript, ember.js, parent-child, hierarchy, siblings

js.

Right Now:
I have a graphView containing 3 tabs A, B, and C.
For each tab A, B or C, each has a view and a coffee.js. In each view, there's a button and in each corresponding coffee.js, each contains a triggerSelf function.

As following:

```
for A: in its view: loadButtonA ; in its aCoffee.js: triggerA function
for B: in its view: loadButtonB ; in its bCoffee.js: triggerB function
for C: in its view: loadButtonC ; in its cCoffee.js: triggerC function
```

What I want to achieve:

```
When I click any button, I want to trigger the other 2 functions in other 2 files.
For example: When I click loadButtonA, I call triggerA, triggerB in bcoffee.js, and triggerC in cCoffee.js
```

Could anyone help please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it through the controller which (presumably) they all share.

```
App.ViewA = Ember.View.extend({
    actions: {
        triggerA: function () {
            this.trigger();
        }
    },

    trigger: function () {
        /* Handle specific here */

        this.get("controller").send("triggerAny", this);
    }
});

App.GraphController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    graphViews: [], // cache all subview instances here
    actions: {
        triggerAny: function (sender) {
            this.get("graphViews").forEach(function (gv) {
                if (gv === sender) {
                    return;
                }
                gv.trigger();
            });
        }
    }
});
```